# Python simplejson not converting true

Tags: python, json, simplejson

Why doesn't this work? I'm reading for simplejson JsonDecoder, true should be parsable and translated to True.

```
% python
>>> import simplejson as json
>>> print json.loads({"bool":true})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'true' is not defined
>>>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The input to `loads` should be a string:

```
>>> json.loads('{"bool":true}')
{u'bool': True}
```

Answer (score 1):

`json.loads` takes a string, which must be wrapped in quotes, like this:

```
o = json.loads(u'{"bool":true}')
print(o) # outputs  {u'bool': True}
```

Note that the `u` (which makes the string a *character* string in Python 2.x) is optional for this input and only becomes necessary if you're using non-ASCII characters such as ü, é, 编, or ℝ.

Comment: This doc is saying it converts from true to True. http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder. Are you saying I have to alter my json because it is being parsed by Python?

Comment: This answer is wrong because the question asks about `loads`, which expects a string.

Comment: @zigg This answer answers the original question, which was about dumps. maverick [changed it significantly](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10543278/revisions). Updated.

Comment: @phihag Thanks for the clarification.  I'll be sure to check edits next time.